# How to get image data for printing on thermal printer using ESC/POS?

Tags: ios, swift, escpos

First I initialize printer(ESC @ ):

```
addBytesCommand(Data(bytes: [0x1B, 0x40]))
```

Then I set the line feed amount(ESC 3 n):

```
addBytesCommand(Data(bytes: [0x1B, 0x33, 24]))
```

Then I'm trying to use (ESC *) command to print image:

```
addBytesCommand(Data(bytes: [0x1B, 0x2A, 33]))

let image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "icon_circle_remove_filled")
let imageWidth = image.size.width
let lowByte = UInt8(Int(imageWidth) & 0x00ff)
let highByte = UInt8((Int(imageWidth) & 0xff00) >> 8)

addBytesCommand(Data(bytes: [lowByte, highByte]))
```

The logic for lowByte and highByte I used from this explanation:
[ESC/POS Image Printing](http://new-grumpy-mentat.blogspot.com/2014/06/java-escpos-image-printing.html).
After that I'm trying to get image image data to send to printer using this extension for UIImage.

```
extension UIImage {
func pixelData() -> [UInt8]? {
    guard let cgImage = self.cgImage else { return nil }

    let size = self.size
    let bitsPerPixel = UInt8(cgImage.bitsPerPixel)
    let bitsPerComponent = cgImage.bitsPerComponent
    let bytesPerRow = cgImage.bytesPerRow

    let dataSize = bytesPerRow * cgImage.height
    var pixelData = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: dataSize)
    let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray()
    let context = CGContext(data: &pixelData,
                            width: Int(size.width),
                            height: Int(size.height),
                            bitsPerComponent: bitsPerComponent,
                            bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow,
                            space: colorSpace,
                            bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.alphaOnly.rawValue)
    context?.draw(cgImage, in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height))

    return pixelData
}
```

And that's where I have problems. I don't understand what `pixelData` contains exactly and how can I transform it to correct type of data? 
What is the correct way to get bitmap information for printing?